# How to handle escape key press event?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In Swift, is there a function in Cocoa framework to handle the press so that you can register which keyboard key has been hit?

I'd like to get the escape key

UPDATED:
i just found that the noise was casued by
 super.keyDown(with: event)
wich is not needed for the thing to work 
why did u add that line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a subclass of `NSWindow` and implement `keyDown` event:

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon.HIToolbox

class CustomWindow: NSWindow {

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        switch Int(event.keyCode) {
        case kVK_Escape:
            print("Esc pressed")
        default:
            break
        }
        super.keyDown(with: event)
    }

}
```

This line:

```
import Carbon.HIToolbox
```

Lets you use handy constants for keys, such as `kVK_Escape`.

Set this class as your main window class in the Interface Builder and you're all set:

[image]

[image]

P.S. To do the same form `NSViewController`, in `viewDidLoad` do:

```
NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
    self.keyDown(with: $0)
    return $0
}
```

P.P.S. To mute "bang" sound, don't call super upon Escape key press - move super call to default:

```
default:
    super.keyDown(with: event)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want any sound on Escape key press, then the following approach should be used:

Make an `NSView` subclass and set it to main view of the view controller:

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon.HIToolbox

class CustomView: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        switch Int(event.keyCode) {
        case kVK_Escape:
            print("Esc pressed")
            return true
        default:
            return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awsome nswer, would it be possible to run the overide function from the main viewcontroler?

Comment: also, when i hit escape in my app it does that bang sound is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: "bang" sound is played because super is called. You can put this line: `super.keyDown(with: event)` to default implementation, thus avoiding it to be called upon Escape key press.

Comment: it seems that my textfield in my app are preventing the function to run it prevents the printing, do you know if there's anyway the setting of my textfield could cause this? I made sure they were all not accepting first responder

Comment: I updated my answer. Try using View Controller implementation. I tested with textfield, works fine (accepts input and escape is handled).

Comment: even when I make a new project the moment I add a textfield it prevents it from working and does the bang sound even if I don't have the super keydown line code in

Comment: "Bang sound" is default, normal behavior as designed by macOS when you hit Escape and it is unhandled.

Comment: To mute bang sound from elsewhere, I believe you might need to override keyDown behavior from everywhere, because your textfield obviously handles it to accept input.

Comment: the function with ur update now works fine, but the bang noise is still there even with keydown line in default https://imgur.com/a/mvIFb

Comment: is there a way to mute it from the textfield with an override function like that one

Comment: Indeed, it persists on typing. Remove super call completely (add `break` instead). This way input will be normal, but sound will be there on Escape press. To remove it completely, I believe textfield should be subclassed.

Comment: is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I tried it again with a new app and the noise appears even when its a new app with nothing on it, no textfield,

Comment: Beep won't occur if you use `NSWindow` approach, with no super call. However, Escape won't be catched if you make other controls first responder. This way you would need to make ViewController catch keyDown events. That's a tricky task you are trying to nail. :)

Comment: This would require some research, I don't have a solution straight away. Consider asking a new question for this.

Comment: alrighr hexfire, i will do my own research i apreacite the great help you gave me

Comment: Glad to assist. Don't hesitate to make a new topic, solution is there for sure.

Comment: Post here whenever you come up with one, I'll come back to continue it with you.

Comment: we got to work by using "import Cocoa

class CustomView: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
} "  and linking it to the view

Comment: Yeah, I came to similar solution yesterday, except that in order for other keys, such as arrows, ctrl, alt, etc work properly, you need to implement that event like this: 
    `override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        switch Int(event.keyCode) {
        case kVK_Escape:
            print("Esc pressed")
            return true
        default:
            return super.performKeyEquivalent(with: event)
        }
    }` and remove implementation from `NSWindow` and `ViewController`. This way there will be no sound and all keys will work properly.

Comment: what do you think of class EscapeKeyNoiseRemoval: NSView {
    override func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return event.keyCode == 53
 }
}    same result?

Comment: @LeoDabus accusing someone of something like this without any proof should be against the rules, too. So  I'd either accept an apology, or a proof that I used (or even saw) your answer. As for calling super, that's a reasonable part of your comment and I will surely add this to the answer, referring your name on your permission.